# TSQL Cross Apply not working as expected

Tags: t-sql, cross-apply

Have 3 tables:

- Users
- Depts (although seems not necessary for the query but...)
- Messages

Users:

```
       UID, DeptID, Name, Surname,  Admin
        U1  DeptA   John    Doe     0
        U2  DeptB   Jack    Fisher  0
        U3  DeptA   Jill    Smith   0
        U4  DeptA   Joan    Green   1
        U5  DeptC   Jeff    Jones   1
        U6  DeptA   Amanda  Reed    0
        ......
```

Depts:

```
       DeptID, DeptName
        DeptA   Denver
        DeptB   Boston
        DeptC   Seattle
```

Messages:

```
        Sender, Receiver, Message, CreatedDate, Seen
            U1      U3      Msg1        20152310    0
            U1      U4      Msg2        20152310    0
            U4      U1      Msg3        20152310    0
            U3      U4      Msg4        20152310    0
            U1      U3      Msg5        20152310    0
            U3      U1      Msg6        20152310    0
```

(Users can send messages only to other users in same Dept)

with as input only one parameter, thus UID

I need to create a list with all Users of same Dept (except input UID) as headers, therefore in the example

```
U3          U4       U6
```

with their details (name, surname) to create the tabs list

and then for each of the UID above, a list with latest 20 messages where U1 is involved both as sender and receiver

To fill the chat sidebar you can see here: http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_4/

clicking on the top right icon

I tried with this.. but have plenty of duplicates that do not know how to remove: perhaps cross apply is not the right command... :-(

```
SELECT  u.UID, 
        u.PWD,
        i.Sender,
        I.MessageText
        .....
FROM (
        SELECT  S.UID,
                S.PWD
            FROM dbo.Users  u
            JOIN dbo.Users  u2  ON  u.DeptID=u2.DeptID
            WHERE u2.UID=@_UID
            ORDER BY u.Admin DESC
        ) AS u
CROSS APPLY 
        (
            SELECT TOP (20) 
                    m.Sender, 
                    m.Message, 
                    m.CreatedDate, 
                    m.Seen
            FROM    dbo.Messages m
            WHERE   m.Sender=@_UID 
            OR      m.Receiver=@_UID
            ORDER BY m.CreatedDate DESC
        ) m;
```

Can suggest what's wrong?

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I can't figure out exactly what your query was trying to do.  But from looking at the page you linked and the description of your problem, it sounds like you want a query to populate the list of users (other than current user) and another to get the messages that pertain to that user.

Consider something like:

```
DECLARE @_UID varchar(2) = 'U3';

-- Query for populating list of users
SELECT [UID], [Name] + ' ' + [Surname] AS [FullName]
FROM [dbo].[Users]
WHERE [UID] <> @_UID
ORDER BY [Admin] DESC, [Surname], [Name];

-- Query for populating messages
SELECT TOP 20 S.[UID] AS [SenderUID], S.[Name] + ' ' + S.[Surname] AS [SenderFullName],
    R.[UID] AS [ReceiverUID], R.[Name] + ' ' + R.[Surname] AS [ReceiverFullName],
    M.[Message], M.[CreatedDate], M.[Seen]
FROM [dbo].[Messages] M
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] S ON S.[UID] = M.[Sender]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] R ON R.[UID] = M.[Receiver]
WHERE @_UID IN(M.[Sender], M.[Receiver])
ORDER BY M.[CreatedDate] DESC;
```

Regarding the usage of APPLY, it is similar to JOIN.  When using JOIN, you are combining a set of results that is known (such as the contents of a table) to another set of results that is also known.  When using APPLY, the right side set of results do not necessarily have to be known - for example, you can use a function to calculate a result based on the left side results.

Comment: Hi! 

Thanks for answering..
Actually my goal was to put all together in 1 single query, but perhaps it is much easier keeping 2 separated queries...
I will think a little again.

Comment: The reason I'd use two queries is because if a user has more than one message, they will be in the results twice - but then you'd have duplicates in your list of users.  Personal experience has also taught me that multiple small queries that return exactly what I want for a particular view is usually faster than trying to use the output of a more complex query for multiple views.

Comment: Yes, I see.. and actually this is what I what I do usually do.. but would like to see if there was an elegant solution with a single query.